# .php file won't display form data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to change my "Submit" button style when a user clicks on it upon submitting the form.

The `action` attribute calls PHP file, but the actual data doesn't display until I remove `onSubmit` attribute from my form. Then I can't use `sendBtn()` function to change the style of the button.

Pseudo-class option is not good, because it would change the style even if the form is empty.

Any ideas?

PS. I'm on local server with MAMP and using Dreamweaver for editing.

```html
<form  class="customform" method="post"  action="emailOnServer.php"  method="post" onSubmit="return sendBtn();"  autocomplete="on" >
   <div class="s-12"  onClick="formFocus()"><input id="imie"  name="imie1"              placeholder="Twoje imię"  type="text" required </input></div>
   <div class="s-12"  onClick="formFocus()"><input id="email" name="email1" placeholder="Twój e-mail"  type="email" required </input></div>
   <div class="s-12" onClick="formFocus()"><textarea placeholder="Wiadomość" id="pole" rows="5" style="resize:none;" required></textarea </input></div>
   <div class="custom2" style="width: 34%; float: right;" ><input id="se" type="submit"  value="Wyślij"  style="background-color:#92c500; color: white; border-color:#6C0;" ></input> </div>           
   <div class="custom1" style="width: 65%;" ><button id="resetButton" onclick="cleanBtn()" type="reset"   style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border-color:#066; border-radius:2px;">Wyczyść </button></div>
   <img id="tick123" src="img2/green-tick-icon-0.png" style="display: none; float:right; position:absolute; right:1%; top:86%; padding:0; margin:0; width: 28px; height: 28px;"/>
   <img id="tick1234" src="img2/green-tick-icon-0.png" style="display: none;  position:absolute; left:58%; top:86%; padding:0; margin:0; width: 28px; height: 28px;"/>
</form> 

<!-- more code to change form style on focus -->

function sendBtn() {
  
  
  if ( document.getElementById('email').value.indexOf("@")> 0 && 
       document.getElementById('email').value.indexOf(".")> 2 && 
       document.getElementById('imie').value != 0 &&
       document.getElementById('email').value != 0 &&
    document.getElementById('pole').value != 0){ 
    
  document.getElementById('se').style.backgroundColor = "#00283A";
  document.getElementById("tick123").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('se').value="Wysłano";
  document.getElementById('email').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('imie').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('pole').disabled=true;
  return true;}}
```

It's from a free template and I know I should've used css stylesheets to make it more readable

This is emailOnServer.php file:

```html
<body>
Hello User  
<?php $name = $_POST['imie1'];
  echo $name; ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Please show us the sendBtn() function. Make sure it returns the correct value to send the form.

Comment: I added more code and it's between `<script></script>` tags.
As far as I know `true` will submit the form and it does. Then I get the .php file in another tab, but it says "Hello User" only.

Comment: Removed tags from title

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML have some errors, e.g.:

```
<input id="imie" ....  type="text" required </input>
// look here                               ^
// the tag is not closed correctly
```

should be

```
<input id="imie"  name="imie1" placeholder="Twoje imię"  type="text" required />
```

Anyway, if you need to remove the `onsubmit` attribute, you can do something like this

```
<form name="myform" ...>
    ...
</form>
```

then, the js

```
var form = document.forms.myform;

form.onsubmit = function(){
    // do stuff
    document.getElementById('se').style.backgroundColor = "#00283A";
    // ...
}
```

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u43a2zp5/1/) has an example code for your requirements. The form elements was simplified.

Comment: OMG! Thank You rogelio :)
I simply did this:  

`var form = document.forms.myForm;
 form.onsubmit = sendBtn ();`  

and it worked!
It doesn't have anything to do with `<input>`  tag because I've tried both ways before